# Roadmap to better data access for asp.net MVC app

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm

I've have quite small asp.net MVC 2 application to maintain/extend. Currently it uses hand written stored procedures + application code for doing data access. Basically what it does is that it loads data and wraps it to POCOs.

Current implementation is tedious to maintain. Especially when I have to add new property - not to mention adding new class/table for doing CRUD. Application has separate caching  that is also hard to maintain - and it has led to a few defects. I would love to get rid off that also.

I 've started to thinking about switching to some ORM tool like NHibernate or Entity Framework.

I have very limited experience when it comes to ORM or data access in general. What are the best practices in this situation? What should I take in consideration before jumping to NHibernate/Entity? And what about the downsides?

Comment: I say don't do it, every application I've worked with using NHibernate/Entity needed to be ported to not using it because of performance reasons.  Don't drink the cool aid.

Comment: @Hogan Could you elaborate on your experience?

Comment: I think Neville got it perfect in his 3rd and 4th paragraph.  They make it slightly easier to do some things but impossible to do many others.  You have to learn them (most will get it wrong at least 3 times). They may not actually be able to provide what you need so you will have to switch back.  These solutions remind me of VB6 back in the day.  Easy to get started, so many use / learn it -- but if you had a real choice why would you ever use it for anything but a POC?

Comment: Please post a question about your design and what can be done to make it easier to maintain.  Then we can get at your real issue and solve that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Best practice" is one of my least favourite words - it's often used to assign more importance to an opinion than it really merits...

Having said that...

First, choose your database access strategy; ORM is the current de-facto industry standard, and you've identified the front runners; see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639043/entity-framework-4-vs-nhibernate) thread for a comparison.

Different database access methodologies trade off different things. The one your app currently uses provides a lot of detailed control over the queries and the way they are mapped to your domain - but at the expense of a lot of hand coding. It's likely to provide the best performance, and the most flexibility; some would argue it's the easiest to maintain because there's no "magic" for developers to get their heads round.

ORM solutions trade performance and control for shorter development and (some argue) easier maintenance. There's a learning curve, and the intermediate layer of "magic" can make some problems harder to identify - the classic anti-pattern with ORM is "loading the entire database into memory", but performance issues can also be tricky to debug. On the other hand, you reduce the overall amount of code, and make simple CRUD operations far easier to build. Developers with experience in ORM will find it easier to maintain; developers who are new to ORM will have to learn the framework.

In general, I think the industry is moving to ORM for applications that don't have extreme performance requirements; it's becoming mainstream, and most developers we interview these days have experience with ORM. However, the learning curve can be quite steep, and there's a definite chicken and egg - which ORM do you choose without having experience of them all? FWIW, I think Steven Lacy's answer is on the money there...

What you're proposing is basically a refactoring. I'd recommend a process along the following lines:

- pick a feature to refactor
- make sure you have a automated tests to ensure it works with the current implementation
- replace the current implementation with your chosen ORM
- run your automated tests to ensure it still works
- rinse and repeat.

I would put at least as much effort into creating the tests as in the refactoring itself - and I would resist the urge to add new features until you've replaced the current implementation.

Make sure your tests include performance and scalability testing.

Comment: Yes, but before I get my hands dirty I have to know if it's a good idea to begin with.

Comment: Ah - in that case, I misunderstood your question. Have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Very Excellent answer Neville -- esp the 3rd and 4th paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

I've used both NHibernate and Entity Framework.

In work we went with Entity Framework because it was easier to convince others to use it rather than an open source application.

The vast majority of the developers I encounter use NHibernate but then both have their disadvantages, they make the amount of work you have to do less when accessing data but they also restrict you.

Currently in EF I face a problem where I can't use Full Text Searches on SQL server because EF doesn't support that. I could do a direct query through the context but I'd much rather use Table Valued Functions which should be very easy to implement with Linq2 whatever but for some reason the EF team haven't gotten around to.

Make sure that you follow a unit of work pattern, your session gets created when it's needed and destroyed at the end of the web request. Both of them are designed to work well under these conditions, do something like hold the context/session in the application scope and you will encounter problems.

Build your application as if you are planning on switching ORM in the future, because as your first commenter said you probably will have to. 
Your Domain Objects should be POCOs, they should have no persistence knowledge

Buy EntityFramework Prof or NHibernate Prof (it will help you optimise queries)

Expect that this will take a fair amount of time to get used to whatever framework you choose. Buy a book and start reading it on your chosen technology, ask questions on stackoverflow early before they become blockers.

Use Code first EF or Fluent Nhibernate, mappings break at runtime, fluent breaks at compile time.

Use Linq2Entities or Linq2Nhibenate, strongly typed queries make life easier about 80% of the time.

Don't have one giant xml file like an EDMX which is horribly difficult to version control.
Beware of code generation, it helps... but it's also dangerous in many situations.

I strongly suggest that you try starting from scratch on a sample project before you alter your existing code. Changing your mind is easier with smaller projects.